# How to access session variables in jinja 2 - Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Do I need to pass session variables manually from Flask to my HTML or are they automatically sent in some way?

Can I do

```
return render_template('index.html')
```

and access a session variable `username`, for example, like `{{session['username'}}` in the HTML file?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In python

```
session['username'] = 'username'
```

in jinja2 you can go

```
{{session['username']}}
```

Comment: be aware that it's `{{ session['username'] }}` (added spaces)

Comment: is it possible to use the session variable the other way round: ie. `set session['username'] = 'username'` in the template?

Comment: The flask tutorial shows the use of dot notation e.g. `session.logged_in`. Reference: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/templates/

Comment: @archienorman to set session in jinja: `{% set _ = session.update({"mykey": "myvalue"}) %}`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to isolate certain parts of your HTML using session you can call the session directly on those elements:

```
{% if session['username'] %}
<li>Logout</li>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

@bpb101 is correct on the Jinja2 format (though left out the spaces as others have mentioned).  In the HTML/Jinja2 template you can simply call the `session` dictionary without passing it to the template:

```
{{ session['username'] }}
```

However the other example, in the Python code, would actually overwrite the value of `session['username']` with the string `'username'`, due to variable assignment.  If you were trying to set a variable to the value of `session['username']` you would use:

```
username = session['username']
```

Otherwise if you just needed to test or use the value for some other reason you can access it directly for example:

```
if session['username'] == some_value:
    return "The username is", session['username']
```

Hopefully that helps for anyone new to Flask or Jinja2 that might wonder why their session variables are being overwritten.