# How can I pass data back and forth between Flask template and Python code (context_processor)?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'll preface with stating I'm still pretty new to Flask. I setup my `app.py` file to import calls from a `view.py` file using the `add_url_rule()`. I'm stuck on how to pass data back and forth between my HTML Template and the Python code.

GOAL: Display HTML snippets based on user selections.
**CLARIFICATION/UPDATE**
Specifically: I need collect a bunch of data. Then I need to form a directory path based on the shelf name selected, get its matching `directory_path` and concatenate it with an `<input type='text'>` directory name, and then add it to the earlier collection of data. The final button on the page will send all the data to be processed.
On my HTML page, I've got an HTML `<form>` to collect a bunch of data. I want to hold that data for the HTML page to use later. Then in the next `<form>`, the user types in a directory name & clicks a button. That `action` retrieves a directory path and concatenates the directory name to the path. The resulting path needs to be added to the earlier collected data. The final button on the page will execute a Python function with all the data.

A work-around solution I've found is using `session`. *See my comment below*.  It's working for me, but not sure if that's bad practice. Is it? That's why I was wondering about `context_processor`.

Shelves are currently stored as a list of dictionaries and a dataframe:

```
shelf_dict = [{'label': 'Shelf Name', 
               'url':'http://shelf_url', 
               'save_dir': 'path/to/save_directory'}, 
              {'label': 'Shelf Name', 
               'url':'http://shelf_url', 
               'save_dir': 'path/to/save_directory'}
             ]
```

Where I'm at: I've figured out that if I pass data from the HTML page to the Python code and back to the same HTML page, I have to pass both the old and new data for that HTML page to render.

1. I've seen how to call the Flask `context_processor` [in the docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/templating/#context-processors). Can the context_processor work here?
2. If so, how would I call it given the structure of my application right now? I've only found examples with the Flask app as an object: `@app.context_processor`. How would I avoid circular referencing here?
3. If context_processor doesn't work for this, is there another approach besides JS/AJAX?

Thanks!

The `test-response` HTML snippet prints the expected info. 
The commented-out `<form>` in the HTML are where I'm stuck.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, app_context
import views

app =  Flask(__name__)
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=views.index)
app.add_url_rule('/index', view_func=views.index)
app.add_url_rule('/download_shelf', 
                  view_func=views.download_shelf_func, 
                  methods=['POST', 'GET'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = f"127.0.0.1:5000"
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

views.py:

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect
from shelf_df import shelf_dict

def download_shelf_func():
    return render_template("download_page.html", shelf_dict=shelf_dict)

def download_options():
    def get_download_path(label):
        return shelf_df[shelf_df['label']==label]['save_dir'].item()

    option_values = {}
    if request.values:
        print(f"{request.args.get('shelf_choice') = }")
        if request.args.get('shelf_choice'):
            shelf_choice = request.args.get('shelf_choice')
            download_path = get_download_path(shelf_choice)
        if request.args.get('pg_size'):
            pg_size = request.args.get('pg_size')
        if request.values.get('sort_order'):
            sort_order = request.args.get('sort_order')
            
    return render_template("download_page.html", 
                            shelf_dict=shelf_dict,
                            option_values={
                                'shelf_choice': shelf_choice, 
                                'pg_size': pg_size, 
                                'sort_order': sort_order,
                                'download_path': download_path
                                })

# def download_func():
#    pass
```

HTML

```
{%block content%} 
  <div class="container">
    <form action="{{ url_for('download_options') }}", id="option-results",
          method="['POST','GET']}}">
      <div class="options">
        <div class="dropdown-menus">
          <div class="shelf-choice">
            <legend> Select shelf:</legend>
            <select id="shelf-choice-select" name="shelf_choice" method="GET" action="/">
              {% for i, label in shelf_dict['label'].items() %}
                  {% if "Test" in label %}:
                    <option value= "{{ label }}" selected>{{label}}</option>"
                  {% else: %}:
                    <option value= "{{ label }}">{{ label }}</option>"
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
          {# Trimmed out pg-size menu #}
        </div>
        {# Trimmed out sort-order buttons #}
      </div>
      <div class="button-group">
        <input type="submit" id="submit-options" value="Set options" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
    
  <div class="container" id="test-response">
    {% if option_values %}
      {% for key, val in option_values.items() %}
        {{ key }}: {{ val }}<br />
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

  {#
  <div class="container">
    {# Need to concatenate a download_path+date # }
    <form action="{{ url_for('download_func') }}" id="newPathName" name="directoryBrowser" method="['POST', 'GET']"> 
      <input type="text" id="directory-name" name="directoryName" placeholder="Today's Date">
      <input type="submit" id="download-btn" name="download_button">
    </form> 
  </div>
  #}

  </div>
```

Comment: normally you send from Python to HTML in `render_template(...)` and back using `<a href=''...">` or `<form>` and this reload page in web browser . But if you want to send something without reloading page then you have to learn `JavaScript` and function `fetch(url, ...)` (which means `AJAX`). Eventually you may use also `websocket` but this also means `JavaScript`

Comment: I don't have a problem reloading the page. It's the `return render_template()` parameters. For example in `def download_options()`, I have to include `shelf_dict` in addition to new data I would need for a later in the page.

Comment: `<form>` needs `method="POST"` or `method="GET"`, not `method="['POST','GET']}}"`. Because in Python you use `request.args` so it needs `method="GET"`. For `method="POST"` it would need `request.form`

Comment: if you don't have a problem reloading the page then I don't know what is the problem. You have `render_template()` to send from `Python` to `template` (and to browser), and you have `<form>` to send from `template` (or rather from browser) to `Python`

Comment: Actually it looks like `session` would serve my purpose since my app is only runs on a local server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611281/9915864 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42013500/9915864. This method requires an `app.secret_key` to be set: https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/flask/sessions

Comment: `session` is for keeping data between requests (between pages, and between functions in Flask) because server doesn't remember user - and if it use threads then every request can be processing by different threads. I never saw if someone use it to set something directly in browser/HTML. You can get value from session and send it to HTML using `render_template` and later you can get value from HTML using `<form>` (`requests.form` or `request.args`) and set value in session - so it still need `render_template` and `<form> ` to send from Flask to HTML and from HTML to Flask.

Comment: Thanks furas. The distinction for what `session` does is helpful. It works for me in this case, but probably isn't good practice. Does `context_processor` do what I'm looking for then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256245/discussion-between-meghan-m-and-furas).